# Flexslider change prevText and nextText after slide changes

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have:

```
    jQuery('.flexslider.home').flexslider({
        animation: 'fade',
        controlsContainer: ".slider-controls",
        directionNav: true,
        manualControls: ".slider-controls ul li",
        //prevText: 'Start',
        //nextText: 'End',
        slideshow: true,
        start: function(slider){
        },
        after: function(slider){
            slider.vars.prevText = 'Hello';
            slider.vars.nextText = 'World';
        }
    });
```

The problem is here that when 'on after' is triggered: slider.vars.prevText = 'Hello'; will set this value, but there is no change triggered on the frontend.

How to solve this issue (i want on slide change to change labels for prevText and nextText)?

Comment: I have a somewhat similar question, do you found any solution?

Comment: I used jQuery selectors and function .html("new name");